# Can't find resource 'data-config.xml' in classpath or '/configs/ifir_feedback', cwd=/home/harishy/opt/solr/solr-6.3.0/server

Tags: solr

How to do full import in PostgreSQL to solr.

I want to full import but i cant not able to do that. I have all files. Here I follow process

1. I create one collection SA_APP_MASTER
2. I have all data in PostgreSQL local.
3. I create one xml file which connect to my local postgresh and select data.
4. I have one more file solrconfig file.

Now my question is that in which directory of my solr I have to store that file so I can do full import .

Comment: Could you share your DIH config?

Answer (score 0):

The Data Import Handler (the one xml file which connect to your local postgres and select data)has to be registered in solrconfig.xml (The solrconfig.xml file is located in the conf/ directory for each collection). For example:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">/path/to/my/DIHconfigfile.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Or you can put your DIH xml file in the same folder where solrconfig.xml is located and register in solrconfig.xml as the following.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">DIHconfigfile.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The only required parameter is the config parameter, which specifies the location of the DIH configuration file that contains specifications for the data source, how to fetch data, what data to fetch, and how to process it to generate the Solr documents to be posted to the index.

You can have multiple DIH configuration files. Each file would require a separate definition in the solrconfig.xml file, specifying a path to the file.